# Getting ssl.SSLError certificate verify failed when trying to connect docker container to cloud Kafka Confluent Cluster

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka

I am using python3.4 in a docker container with the following Dockerfile contents:

```
# Python 3.4 necessary for kafka module
FROM python:3.4

COPY frontTags.py .

RUN pip install sql sqlalchemy kafka boto3 psycopg2 pandas typing

CMD [ "python3", "./frontTags.py" ]
```

Uisng the kafka-python module to instantiate KafkaConsumer and connect:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('front_data', 
    bootstrap_servers=kafka_secrets['bootstrap_servers'], 
    security_protocol='SASL_SSL',
    sasl_mechanism='PLAIN',
    sasl_plain_username=kafka_secrets['sasl_plain_username'], 
    sasl_plain_password=kafka_secrets['sasl_plain_password'], 
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    enable_auto_commit=True,
    group_id='front_test1')
```

Causes the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in get_consumer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 324, in __init__
    self._client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, **self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 216, in __init__
    self._bootstrap(collect_hosts(self.config['bootstrap_servers']))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 250, in _bootstrap
    bootstrap.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 362, in connect
    if self._try_handshake():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 426, in _try_handshake
    self._sock.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 813, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)
```

Comment: 1) Python 3.4 is super old. Please update. 2) `confluent-kafka-python` package is completely separate from `kafka` (which is no longer maintained and was renamed to `kafka-python`), and has better support for Confluent Cloud, perhaps

Comment: So I am working on using this module instead. Seeing a different error when trying to load it into a docker container:

/tmp/pip-install-houvu0o2/confluent-kafka_634a645187c2433698de935715fd34bb/src/confluent_kafka/src/confluent_kafka.h:23:10: fatal error: librdkafka/rdkafka.h: No such file or directory

Comment: I used `FROM python:3.9` + `RUN pip install confluent_kafka` and I can create a non-SSL consumer

Comment: Yea even with the above 2 lines its failing with the same error related to librdkafka:

FROM python:3.9 

RUN pip install confluent_kafka

Comment: Turns out specifying the platform with --platform linux/amd64 worked? 

docker build --platform linux/amd64 --tag front-data .

Comment: I am already on an amd64 system. If you are using ARM, then you will have to rebuild librdkafka from source, I believe. However, `kafka-python` should still work with Confluent Cloud. I was just telling you that `pip install kafka` is probably not what you want